# MySQL table -> Can you return the same row multiple times, in the same query?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT * FROM menu WHERE item_id = 1 OR item_id = 2 OR item_id = 3;
```

The above statement returns 3 rows.
But the statement below only returns 2 rows.

```
SELECT * FROM menu WHERE item_id = 1 OR item_id = 1 OR item_id = 2;
```

And I understand why like, but is there a way to force item_id 1 to be returned twice???

Example of what I want to be returned:

> id -> 1 Chips €2.50
>   id -> 1 Chips €2.50
>   id -> 2 Coke €1.60
>   --------------------
>   Total €6.60

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could join on another table, for example

```
SELECT * FROM menu
INNER JOIN order_items ON menu.item_id = order_items.item_id
WHERE order_id = 123;
```

Or just duplicate them in your application.

You shouldn't really need to do what you're asking for.

Comment: Yeah no ur rite like, duplicating it with php is easy enuff. Thanks a lot lads!

Comment: Fwiw, I wandered upon this thread because I need to produce multiple row copies for a population script.  Diff use-case than above, but it is sometimes necessary, without access to application-tier migration.

Answer (score 10):

You would have to do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM menu WHERE item_id = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM menu WHERE item_id = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM menu WHERE item_id = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You just make a join among its aliases, e.g.

```
select top 5 * from item a, item b where a.itemid =1
```

It will print data like the following.

```
1 abc
1 abc
1 abc
1 abc
1 abc
```

Hope, you will understand.

Answer (score 0):

You need a way to generate a dummy rowset to do this, and `MySQL` lacks it.

You can do the following:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  1 AS x
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  1 AS x
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  2 AS x
        ) dummy
JOIN    menu
ON      menu.id = dummy.x
```

Answer (score 0):

Use unions:

```
SELECT * FROM menu WHERE item_id = 1
  UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM menu WHERE item_id = 1
  UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM menu WHERE item_id = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

why do you want to query db twice for same thing. Just query once and do the modification 
(add rows or display same row twice) using programming language you are using.

Something like

```
id -> 1 Chips €2.50 X 2
id -> 2 Coke €1.60
--------------------
Total €6.60
```

Answer (score 0):

The first answer looks wrong.  It should be left outer join with order_items as first table...

```
SELECT * FROM order_items oi
left outer JOIN menu m
ON oi.item_id = m.item_id
WHERE order_id = 123;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but i see that everyone is missing a point here. This is not a question of what query to send to the database. This is a question of database design.

DJDonal even gives us an example of the result they wish to see and that is not a result made by one table.

There has to be an article table which includes article ID, Name or Description and price to contain information like Chips, ID 1, €2.50 and Coke, ID 2, €1.60.

And a second table made up of shopping list ID and article ID and an incremental ID for good measures.

Then you query the shopping list table with a specific list ID and join the article table onto it to get the descrition and price.

The stuff that should be handled by the program is how to create the list and add several entries with the same articles into that list and save it into the shopping list table.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).