# mysql select rows with same ids and preserve their order?

Tags: mysql, select, rows, preserve

just a quick question:

i have to have one single query that has multiple rows - some rows are identicle - and the order of rows must be preserved in the result -

some idea of what im refering to:

```
SELECT id,date 
FROM items 
WHERE id IN (1,2,1,3) 
ORDER BY id=1 DESC,id=2 DESC,id=1 DESC,id=3 DESC;
```

unfortunately mysql result is this:

```
1,2,3
```

not 1,2,1,3

it removes the duplicate which i have to have in my result to display in multiple panels on the same webpage -

i really dont want to loop thru each id one by one to get them the way i want to display -

is there a way to actually have one single query that will preserve the order and pull out rows based on request whether its unique or not -

Comment: I think your data model design is not so good.Did you have primary key as autoincrement?

Comment: yes - the id is autoincremented in the db table -

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109113/mysql-table-can-you-return-the-same-row-multiple-times-in-the-same-query

Comment: If id is aoutoincremented, then no possible duplicate rows exists, so what you mean by WHERE id IN (1,2,1,3) - you have 2 times id = 1

Comment: that was an abstract idea to describe the result i need to output - if thats confusing then my sincere applogy -

Comment: You potentially should have described your specific problem rather than an abstract.  If you describe your specific problem then your answers will be more fitting.  If you try and generalise, things may well get lost.  Also by being specific you open the floor to alternative methods which may give a better way to achieve the same goal.  There's usually multiple paths to the same destination.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing what you are trying to, just select the unique rows you need.  In the frontend code, store each unique row once in a key=>value structure, where key is the item ID and value is whatever data you need about that item.

Once you have that you can use frontend logic to output them in the desired order including duplicates.  This will reduce the amount of redundant data you are trying to select.

For example **This is not usable code - exact syntax required depends on your scripting language**

```
-- setup a display order
displayOrder= [1,2,1,3];

-- select data from database, order doesn't matter here
SELECT id,date 
FROM items 
WHERE id IN (displayOrder);


-- cache the results in a key=> value array
arrCachedRows = {};
for (.... each db row returned ...) {
    arrCachedRows[id] = date;
}

-- Now output in desired order
for (listIndex in displayOrder) {
    -- Make sure the index is cached
    if (listIndex exists in arrCachedRow) {
        echo arrCachedRows[listIndex ];
    }
}
```

**If you must persist in using UNION despite my warnings**

If you go against the above recommendation and absolutely MUST have them back in 1 query in that order then add on an additional row which will enforce the row order.  See below query where I use variable @subIndex to add an incrementing value as subIndex.  This in turn lets you reorder by that and it'll be in the requested order.

```
SELECT
    i.*
FROM (
    SELECT @subIndex:=@subIndex+1 AS subIndex, id, date FROM items where id = 1
    UNION
    SELECT @subIndex:=@subIndex+1 AS subIndex, id, date FROM items where id = 2
    UNION
    SELECT @subIndex:=@subIndex+1 AS subIndex, id, date FROM items where id = 1
    UNION
    SELECT @subIndex:=@subIndex+1 AS subIndex, id, date FROM items where id = 3
) AS i,(SELECT @subIndex:=0) v
ORDER BY i.subIndex
```

Or a slightly cleaner version that keeps item selection until the outside and hides the subindex

```
SELECT
    items.*
FROM items
-- initialise variable
INNER JOIN (SELECT @subIndex:=0) v
-- create a meta-table with the ids desired in the order desired
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT @subIndex:=@subIndex+1  AS subIndex, 1 AS id
    UNION
    SELECT @subIndex:=@subIndex+1  AS subIndex, 2 AS id
    UNION
    SELECT @subIndex:=@subIndex+1  AS subIndex, 1 AS id
    UNION
    SELECT @subIndex:=@subIndex+1  AS subIndex, 3 AS id
) AS i
ON i.id = items.id
-- order by the subindex from i
ORDER BY i.`subIndex` ASC
```

Comment: like i said - i really dont want to loop thru each id one by one to get them the way i want to display -

Comment: You are only defining your display order once.  You can have the same effect by using UNION etc however it will be less efficient and less scaleable.  Using this method it doesn't matter how many id's you add into displayOrder, it will work.

Comment: thanks simon - i have a problem with union all above stmt - it wont return the same order - i have to have the order in place - so the results are all ordered in and out -

Comment: so, ORDER BY i.index ASC - will produce new order, which it looks like, or will preserve the original order? pls clarify it - thanks!

Comment: The @subIndex:=@subIndex+1 adds a column that increments, so 1, 2, 3, 4, which I have named subIndex in the subquery `i`.  This is then considered static in the outer query hence the `ORDER BY i.index ASC`.  The `id`s will still be in the order you specify in the built `UNION` so long as you include that `ORDER BY i.subIndex ASC`

Comment: The subquery exists only to order the fields in the order you are wanting.  It joins onto the `items` table, and so you can change the fields you are requesting in the outer `SELECT`, i.e. instead of `SELECT items.*` you might use `SELECT items.id, items.date`, or any other fields from the items table.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to include the records with id=1 and the order doesn't matter as long as you get them, you can split your query into two queries, one for (1,2,3) union all the other query for id=1 or just do:

```
... In (1,2)
Union all
... In (1,3)
```

Example:

```
  Select * from
  (Select case id when 1 then 1 when 2 then 2 as pseudocol, othercolumns
  From table where Id in (1,2)
  Union all
  Select case id when 1 then 3 when 3 then 4 as pseudocol, othercolumns
  From table where Id in (1,3)) t order by pseudocol
```

Comment: the order is of the essence, guys.

Comment: The union all option I wrote as the last option will return the records in the order you want them. Did you try it?

Comment: thanks icarus - i have a problem with union all above stmt - it wont return the same order - i have to have the order in place - so the results are all ordered in and out

Comment: Dude, then add a pseudo column in the select statements that would indicate the order you want and alias the whole union all and do order by on this pseudo column.

Comment: @user1228311 check my final example

Comment: i give up - nothing works from this page - either mysql error produced or zero results from the above queries - so i had to use a loop to select items one by one - there are 10 of them sofar - could be more so i have to continue looking for the right query - maybe someone eventually write one up that works flawlessly - 

no offence here and i appreciate every answer above -

Answer (score 1):

Your query as it stands will never work, because duplicate values in a list of values of an `IN` clause are ignored. The *only* way to make this work is by using `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT id, date FROM items where id = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT id, date FROM items where id = 2
UNION ALL
SELECT id, date FROM items where id = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT id, date FROM items where id = 3;
```

But to be frank, I suspect your data model so far past screwed it's unusable.

Comment: I'd agree with your final sentiment

Comment: It is not the _only_ way. There are others.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
SELECT
    id,
    date
FROM items
WHERE id IN (1,2,1,3)
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(id, '1,2,1,3')
```

Comment: Will sort 1,1,2,3, as the `FIND_IN_SET()` values are `1,2,1,4`.

Answer (score 1):

Another scrupulous way to answer a suspicious question:

```
SELECT 
      items.id, 
      items.date 
FROM 
      items 
  JOIN
      ( SELECT 1 AS id, 1 AS ordering
      UNION ALL 
        SELECT 2, 2
      UNION ALL 
        SELECT 1, 3
      UNION ALL 
        SELECT 3, 4
      ) AS auxilary
    ON 
      auxilary.id = items.id 
ORDER BY 
      auxilary.ordering
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach (untested, but should give you the idea):

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tt (id INT, ai int unsigned auto_increment primary key);
INSERT INTO tt (id) VALUES (1), (2), (1), (3);
SELECT
    id,
    date
FROM items JOIN tt USING (id)
ORDER BY tt.ai;
```

keeps the given order.

Comment: Similar to my answer. But you do need 2 columns on the temp table. One for joining and one for the ordering.

Comment: Oops, you do have 2 columns! The values should be: `VALUES (1), (2), (1), (3)`

Comment: I have - mine are `id` and `ai` (for autoincrement), yours are `id` and `ordering`. But a temptable is probably "friendlier" to data insertion, i. e. the query is easier to build, depending on the programming language used.

Comment: This suggestion would be rather painful, the use of a temporary table where not necessary is overkill.

Comment: IMO it is not as painful as having to build a query containing dozens of `UNION` orgies...