# updating sql values with array which have a couple times occured items

Tags: php, sql, query-optimization

While i am coding a shopping site, I need to update product stock.
But the thing is, naturally shopping cart can have the same items a couple of times.
What is the best way for updating it?

I tried `IN` but the following SQL query returns 3 items.

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM  `products` 
WHERE id
IN ( 3, 4, 4, 6 ) 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Here is my solution but, I don't think this is the best one.

```
$cart = array(1,3,4,4,5,8,22,22);
$itemlist = array_count_values($cart);

foreach($itemlist as $itemid=>$ocurrence){
    $SQL = "UPDATE products SET stock = stock-".$ocurrence." WHERE id = ".$itemid;
    mysql_query($SQL);
}
```

Comment: I think this method is just fine.  You sort of have to do updates in a loop if they're getting different values.

Comment: Agree with @MichaelBerkowski.  Unless you have a demonstrable performance issue (e.g., a large volume of users, or a large number of products/carts), I would stick with the method you have.  It may be possible to execute the update in a single query with a little more clever coding, but it will be a complex solution that is harder to maintain in the long run.

Comment: You've probably heard it before, but consider moving to a newer API which supports prepared statements, such as MysQLi or PDO. That would actually improve performance of the loop a little, as well as increase security in other queries.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski that is my second shopping site, and site traffic just scares me. I'll go with that then. Thank you. I have no idea about PDO if queries are the same. I can change it but otherwise i can't for now.

Comment: The only better solution would be to store the shopping cart in the database.  Then you can do the update by joining the tables.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM menu WHERE item_id = 1
  UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM menu WHERE item_id = 1
  UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM menu WHERE item_id = 2
```

Check this link:
[MySQL table -> Can you return the same row multiple times, in the same query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109113/mysql-table-can-you-return-the-same-row-multiple-times-in-the-same-query)

Answer (score 0):

if possible create a seperate item_cart, table which will have (cart_id, item_id , product_id) as primary key. from here you can get do a group by on product_id to see how many no of product sold.

```
select product_id, count(product_id) as "No of Product Sold" from item_cart
group by product_id
```

your php code will update no of products in stock coloumn perfectly.

If possible you try setting triggers for updatin stock columns whenever any product is sold.