# Is there any built-in list operator in mysql to get the duplicate selection

Tags: mysql

The following query returns only 1 row. Is there any built-in list operator in mysql to get the duplicate selection (1.e) to get 3 rows instead of 1 row?

select * from table where column in (1,1,1);

This is used to do some aggreate (sum) function on the table.

Comment: What does "duplicate selection (1.e) " mean???

Comment: I don't understand the question. Please clarify. Some sample data plus expected result might help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL table -> Can you return the same row multiple times, in the same query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109113/mysql-table-can-you-return-the-same-row-multiple-times-in-the-same-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that this is really helpful (don't know what you want to achieve and most likely there is a better approach for your problem) but you can use a `UNION ALL` select to create a result set containing the same row three times:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
    SELECT * FROM table WHERE cola = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM table WHERE cola = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM table WHERE cola = 1
) AS x
```

But as I said: most likely this is not the solution to your problem.