# Select the same row and display it many times

Tags: php, mysql

I need to make a `select` that returns objects with `IDs` in specified `array`. But it would be very helpful if I could get in return the same object as many times as it was specified in `closure`. Even that this object is only once in `database`. For example

```
SELECT * FROM `T` WHERE `id` IN (1, 1, 2)
```

I would like it to return 3 rows - 2x first one. And it's important for me that these results are in order that was specified in closure. Is this possible with `MYSQL`?

Comment: what problem you are facing right now? and two times `1` will gave you same result as it will give for `IN(1,2)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL table -> Can you return the same row multiple times, in the same query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109113/mysql-table-can-you-return-the-same-row-multiple-times-in-the-same-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM T WHERE item_id = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM T WHERE item_id = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM T WHERE item_id = 2
```

Using `union all`, you concatenate all the statements (which only return 1 row)

Comment: Thanks, this works just like I need it to. Is this going to have significant impact on performance comparing to normal `IN` statement?

Answer (score 0):

You can also write.

Because UNION ALL always uses a memory table to hold the results. 
You can keep the memory table much smaller when you only define numbers.

I also assume that the column id is a auto_incremented column with a primary key. 
Without a index on the id column joining isn't a great idea.

```
SELECT 
 T.*
FROM (
  SELECT 
   1 AS number
  FROM DUAL

  UNION ALL 

  SELECT 
   1 AS number
  FROM DUAL

  UNION ALL

  SELECT 
   2 AS number
  FROM DUAL
)
 AS numbers
INNER JOIN 
 T
ON 
 T.id = numbers.number
ORDER BY 
 numbers.number ASC
```